# Omniture App measurement for iphone

Tags: iphone, adobe-analytics

Could someone please help with implementation details for Omniture's app measurement iphone library ? I have linked both the dev and release libraries into my app, I instantiate them using the singleton method (getInstance) and they call the 'track' method on the instance....something along these lines.

```
OMAppMeasurement *s = [OMAppMeasurement getInstance];
s.account = @"";
s.debugTracking = YES;
[s track];
```

I cannot see any data on my dashboards, the s.account has a value, but I'm not sure if I'm supplying the correct one. Could some confirm what that value should be? I'm I missing out something fundamental here, as far as I can see I'm following the (very very light )online documentation by the book. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

The account name is the report suite name. From what I understand you have to get this from whoever has information about the sitecatalyst account. I got it, but still cannot find the reported data within sitecatalyst. Did you make any progress?
This is the code I use.

```
//Instantiate instance
OMAppMeasurement * s = [OMAppMeasurement getInstance]; 
//Setup application config variables 
s.account = @"string"; 
//s.ssl = YES;

//Omniture
OMAppMeasurement * s = [OMAppMeasurement getInstance];
//Set Variables
s.pageName = @"CategoryController"; 
s.channel = @"CategoryController";
//clears any previously set value for channel 
s.prop1 = @"CategoryController";
//clears any previously set value for prop1 
s.debugTracking = YES;
[s track];
```

Answer (score 1):

the s.account value is the ReportSuiteID setted at the creation of the report suite.
You can find it in the Admin->ReportSuite page on the right sie of the ReportSuiteName.

Claudio.